# Invalid usage of aggregate function Sum() and Type: String

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a data table and a column contains int values. I have not specified the column with any datatype. When I perform the following.

```
object sum = dttest.Compute("sum(Value)", "");
```

I am getting below error.

> *Invalid usage of aggregate function Sum() and Type: String.*

And I tried converting column value to int using

```
object sum = dttest.Compute("sum(Convert(Value, 'System.Int32'))","");
```

again I am getting another error

> *Syntax error in aggregate argument: Expecting a single column argument
>   with possible 'Child' qualifier.*

When I specify the datatype for the column, first code will return correct value. But in my case I can't specify column datatype. Any one having solution ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use LINQ to Datatable:

```
 var result = dttest.AsEnumerable()
                    .Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x["Value"]));
```

Example how to `Sum` for specific name:

```
 var result = dttest.AsEnumerable()
                    .Where(r => r.Field<string>("Name") == "FilterName")
                    .Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x["Value"]));
```

Comment: Thanks, Got the result. Can i perform any record filteration process here? I dont want to perform sum() on all records.

Comment: @XavierDennis: Yes, you can use `Where`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
object sum = dttest.Compute("Sum(Value)", "[Value] IS NOT NULL");
```

**Sample code**

```
    static DataTable GetTable()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        table.Rows.Add(null, "a");
        table.Rows.Add(50, "a");
        table.Rows.Add(10, "a");
        table.Rows.Add(21, "b");
        table.Rows.Add(100, "b");
        return table;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable dt =GetTable();
        var str = dt.Compute("Sum(Value)", "Name='a' and Value is not null");
    }
```

You can't Call Sum with Convert, but you can try below

```
DataTable dt =GetTable();
dt.Columns.Add("temp", typeof(int), "Convert(Value, 'System.Int32')");
var str = dt.Compute("Sum(temp)", "Name='a' and Value is not null");
```

Comment: Still getting same cast error. All the values in table are int type.

Comment: @XavierDennis check my updated answer, it is working fine with Compute and no errors.

Comment: But problem is, i have not specified the data type of the column. Datatable is filled from an sql query. What ever the column returning from sql query will be populated in datatable.

Comment: can you update the question with how you  get data from database and what is the column type of `Value` in db?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
dttest.Compute("Sum(Convert([Value], 'System.Int32'))","[Value] IS NOT NULL");
```

Comment: Im getting build error "No overload for method 'Compute' takes 1 arguments"

Answer (score 0):

When the program try it sum a datatable column which  declared as string this error occur.
Use the below code to make compute operation on string column.

```
dtTable.Compute("Sum(Convert(" + col_Name + ", 'System.Int32')","");
```

Comment: Depending on how you populate your DataTable, you should  just be able to change the database column type to int, decimal, etc. I was getting this error and I had inadvertently created the column as a varchar(). Changed it to an int() and the error went away. Yes, not every single person has access to make changes on the db, but if you do, this is probably better than converting a string just to sum it.